# Funnel-like visualization for a pipeline - two axis and groups-bys

Tags: pandas, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

looking for some advice on data-viz !

I have a pipeline, and at each step of the pipeline, the amount of elements goes down.
That could be a simple funnel visualization.

However, for all the element, I want to group them, twice actually:

- Two big groups (which are mutually exclusive), with groups inside for the elements => I was thinking of adding a middle axis to my funnel, and one group on each side, as they will evolve independantly.
- In each of those big groups, I want to group again my element by something they have in common, each of the groups having a different color, and people being able to follow that color over the different sections of the funnel.

Now, where I need help :D

1. Does my approach looks correctly?
2. Does this kind of graph has a more specific name than just funnel?
3. Is there, by any chance, a javascript or python library out there that could give me some of the features I am looking for?

Thanks !